# Alternate method to using QPainter to display frames from camera feed on QML frontend

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The following is the method used to display a frame on the frontend:

Frame is grabbed from cv::VideoCapture object inside QRunnable function

```
void CameraFeedGrabber::run()
{


    while(mStopCapture)
    {
        cv::Mat mat;
        bool isFrameGrabbed = cap->read(mat);// gets the next frame

        if(isFrameGrabbed  )
        {

            emit frameAvailable(mViewId,mat.clone());
        }+;
    }

}
```

Signal is emitted from the above class to an interfacing class

```
void QmlInterface::processFrames(int cameraId, cv::Mat mat, bool sessionStatus)
{
    if(GlobalSettings::mQmlVideoIntList.size() > 0)
    {
        cv::Mat matToSend = mat.clone();
        cv::cvtColor(matToSend, matToSend, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        QImage qFrame1 =  QImage((uchar*)matToSend.data, matToSend.cols, matToSend.rows, matToSend.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        GlobalSettings::mQmlVideoIntList[0]->setFrame(qFrame1);
    }

    if(sessionStatus)
        mFrameAssigner->setFrame(mat);
}
```

Interfacing class calls function inside display class to update the frame

```
QmlVideoInterface::QmlVideoInterface(QQuickItem *parent):
    QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{


}

void QmlVideoInterface::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->drawImage(0, 0, mCurrentImage.scaled(_imageWidth, _imageHeight, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
}

void QmlVideoInterface::setFrame(const QImage &image)
{
    mutex.lock();
    mCurrentImage = image.copy();
    update();
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Using this method works fine when displaying smaller frames but for larger frames, for instance, 1920*1080 uses around 20% CPU (i7 6700 @ 3.40 Ghz). With video analytics also running in the backend this is too costly for simply displaying the frame. Is there an alternative to this method?

Comment: I think you're using threads? Are you sure that the problem is caused by the painting and not by another part of your code? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc code is edited to contain entire method

Comment: Without displaying of the feed the application runs at around 7% CPU

Comment: I recommend you to test the item by creating fictitious images without using the thread or opencv so you can see if the Item generates that 13% load.

Comment: In addition it is always advisable to give it a time when a while True is executed, for example give it a 10ms sleep: `QThread::msleep(10)`

Comment: After creating a function that simply loads a QImage (exempt from any threading or opencv) and sends the image to the painter (Image resolution is 1920*1080), I still get 14% CPU usage

Comment: How often do you create a new QImage ?, remember that the period between frame and frame is about 30ms

Comment: Called on a timer for every 30ms, there was a reduction in CPU usage when called at this interval, but not enough of a reduction to justify the decrease in the latency of the camera feed